# Using ToLookup too slow (C#, .NET Core, EntityFrameworkCore)

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I need help to speed up this chunk of code somehow.

Using `EntityFrameworkCore 3`, `.NET Core 3.1`.

```
var groups = _context.IPItem
                .OrderBy(x => x.ParentId).ThenBy(x => x.OrderInIndex)
                .Where(x => x.BibNum == BibNumber)
                .ToLookup(x => x.ParentId, x => new IPItemViewModel
                {
                    IPItemId = x.IPItemId,
                    ResourceText = x.ResourceText,
                    ResourceLink = x.ResourceLink,
                    FullResourceLink = x.FullResourceLink,
                    OrderInIndex = x.OrderInIndex,
                    ExtraInfo = x.ExtraInfo
                });
```

The `"ToLookup"` can be a big bottleneck when there are several layers of nested `ParentIds` associated with the particular `BibNumber`.

I'd love to see what the `"ToLookup"` part looks like in `TSQL` but can't seem to find a way to do that.

I was trying to figure out if changing `ToLookup` to `GroupBy`, might be faster, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Any suggestions?

The table for this has these properties:

```
IPItemId int NOT NULL, Primary Key
ParentId int NULL
BibNum string NOT NULL
ResourceText string NOT NULL
ResourceLink string NOT NULL
FullResourceLink string NOT NULL
OrderInIndex int NULL
ExtraInfo string NOT NULL
```

Comment: Anyway, I doubt GroupBy would be faster on _generation_, but it's literally just changing it to `.Select(x => new { ParentId = x.ParentId; /* other stuff */ }).GroupBy(x => x.ParentId)` and then dealing with the resulting Grouping<a'>; should take about 2 minutes to swap and compare. Convert ToDictionary later if/as relevant (outside of queryable).

Comment: It could always be a _quantity_ of data as well. Ensure that any filters and/or pagination are pushed up to the IQueryable-level.

Comment: `ToLookup` is `Enumerable` extension method, thus has nothing to do with SQL (executes client side).  If you have performance issue, it has to be in the db part of the query (before `ToLookup()`)  - you can verify that by replacing `ToLookup` with `ToList`. I would try removing `OrderBy` / `ThenBy` and also add `AsNoTracking()`.

Comment: For sure it is the `ToLookup` part that is slow. I have tried splitting the code as follows and putting a timer around both section. This part is fast:

`var groupList = _context.IndexPageItem
                .OrderBy(x => x.ParentId).ThenBy(x => x.OrderInIndex)
                .Where(x => x.BibNum == BibNumber);`

Comment: This part can take a long time if there are a lot of nested ParentIds:

`var groups = groupList.ToLookup(x => x.ParentId, x => new IndexPageItemVM
                {
                    IndexPageItemId = x.IndexPageItemId,
                    ResourceText = x.ResourceText,
                    ResourceLink = x.ResourceLink,
                    FullResourceLink = x.FullResourceLink,
                    OrderInIndex = x.OrderInIndex,
                    ExtraInfo = x.ExtraInfo
                });`

Comment: I assume this particular case has already been solved, but for future reference: Benchmarking the `.OrderBy(x => x.ParentId).ThenBy(x => x.OrderInIndex).Where(x => x.BibNum == BibNumber)` part shows fast performance because **those calls don't evaluate anything**. Linq queries are evaluated lazily. The `.ToLookup` call triggers the earlier operators to evaluate, so all the time seems to be spent on that call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to speed up the query by implementing an Index on the table in the database.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_IndexPageItem_bibNum_parent 
   ON IPItem (bibNum ASC, ParentId ASC, orderInIndex ASC);
```

It only sped up the process when I implemented the Index before inserting everything to the database, and not after.
Thanks all for taking a look, appreciated!